# How can I use multiple properties files and encryption keys in gitlab CI/CD stages

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, yaml, sonarqube

I have multiple properties files, encryption keys and others files stored across multiple location in my project. In the sonarqube stage, I am doing mvn sonar:sonar which basically builds the complete project as per my understanding. I know that mvn sonar:sonar stage happens on root or home directory where I had to create .m2 folder as well on root.

I am running this on Java maven project.

On my local or in other stages everything is working fine as it uses the local project directories where it finds all the properties file and project.

Can someone let me know what is the best practice/ way to run mvn sonar:sonar stage so that I don't have to individually create and copy files and folders as per local.

Comment: Any help on this ?